# Where are fonts loaded in an Angular app using the Angular Material core theme?

Tags: angular, fonts, angular-material

I'm trying to determine what font weights are included by default in my application. We're using Angular 5.2.5 and Angular Material2 (v5.2.1), with the AM core theme enabled:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
```

Our custom theme defines color only. No font links are specified, yet Roboto is still used as the default as seen in the document inspector:

```
.mat-card[_ngcontent-c36] {
    font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.mat-h2[_ngcontent-c36], .mat-title[_ngcontent-c36] {
    font: 500 20px/32px Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
```

All the documentation and tutorials I find describe how to customize or override default fonts. Where is the Roboto font loaded, and/or where can I determine what font weights are included? I'd like to customize the available font weights.

Comment: You mean you want the list of fonts supported by the **Angular Material**?

Comment: Nope. (I'm not even sure what that means as any font can be loaded.) I'm asking where fonts are loaded in a brand new, generic, default application generated with Angular CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Angular Material won't load the default Roboto font for you. You have to include them yourself.

See the [docs (Typography > Usage)](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#usage) for more info.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case, as the only font link we have in our app is for icons.

Comment: @isherwood I'm sorry, could you rephrase?

Comment: The Roboto font is not included as a link in our stylesheets or elsewhere, yet it shows up across Angular Material's CSS.

Comment: Yeah... Angular Material **expects** you to include the Roboto font, they won't provide it for you.

Comment: The docs at that point may assume that no theme is loaded. Maybe the core theme loads the font.

Comment: Well, it turns out that you're right. My mistake was in thinking that the Computed styles in Chrome indicated what's actually applied. That's not the case. The Roboto font was in fact *not* loaded.

Answer (score 1):

A better explanation of the problem:

Indeed the docs describe you need too add the url for the fonts. However this is only needed for your own paragraphs, header, spans, etc... Any material component is already using the Roboto font. Even without adding the link in the index.html. I guess the OP is asking where these font are coming from as he does not include them.

Possible answer:

Both the [icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons) and the [fonts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/roboto-fontface) are available on npm. So my guess is the components simply have that dependency. in the network tab there isn't any call for them so them already must be there.

Comment: Thanks. We are adding the `mat-typography` class on several primary elements, which therefore styles the generic elements you mentioned. I think you may be right about them being package deps, but I still need to determine what weights are loaded (and it would be nice to know what package loads them). I can experiment in my browser's document inspector, but that seems less than satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure they are loaded at all? 
To check it you open google chrome dev tool -> network -> filter requests by fonts. If you don't see fonts load - you are OK. But if you see them there - you can go deeper and investigate who initiates request by hovering over "initiator".

[image]

Comment: They must be loaded--as I posted in the question the Robot font is being applied. It doesn't appear in the Network tab. The only font that does is for icons.

Answer (score 1):

**How is roboto font loaded?**

Well, if you do not include a link URL to the Roboto font, it will **not** be loaded.

The CSS style from material will specify the following font and fallback

```
Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif
```

but the Roboto font will not be actually loaded (just because you specify it in CSS does not mean that it gets applied). Instead, if you do not include the font yourself anywhere, the browser will not be able to find Roboto font and will use the fallback font `Helvetica Neue`; if the browser cannot find that font, it will then use the browser's default font , which is `Times new Roman` by default  for Chrome (you can check default fonts in chrome by entering this in the url bar:  chrome://settings/fonts)

To verify the above, just manually remove `Roboto,` from the CSS inspector for a given element and you'll see that the displayed font on the page does not actually change. This is because the browser is already using the default font.

**Where is the Roboto font specified?**

Fonts are specified in `@angular/material/_theming.scss` file (line 1443 for v 5.2.0)

```
@function mat-typography-config(
  $font-family:   'Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif',
```

You included that file yourself with the import

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
```

**Where are font sizes specified ?**

Default font sizes are included in the same file as above by the `mat-typography-level-to-styles` mixin (line 1498 for h2 for v 5.2.0)

```
  .mat-h2, .mat-title, #{$selector} h2 {
      @include mat-typography-level-to-styles($config, title);
       margin: 0 0 16px;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.angular-cli.json`

```
...
"styles": [
    "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500"
    "assets/scss/styles.scss",
]
...
```

`client/src/styles.scss` or any style file

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300');
```

Comment: You seem to be proposing two different ways to include font files. That's not what I'm asking for. Do I misunderstand?